# Docker compose selenium connect to another app localhost

Tags: python, docker, selenium, docker-compose

I am trying to run selenium tests locally. I have both Selenium Grid / and Fronend set up with docker-compose. However I am having trouble accessing frontend ports as `browser.get('http://localhost:8000/upload')`.

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  chrome:
    image: selenium/node-chrome:4.0.0-beta-3-prerelease-20210402
    volumes:
      - /dev/shm:/dev/shm
    depends_on:
      - selenium-hub
    environment:
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_HOST=selenium-hub
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_PUBLISH_PORT=4442
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_SUBSCRIBE_PORT=4443
    ports:
      - "6900:5900"

  selenium-hub:
    image: selenium/hub:4.0.0-beta-3-prerelease-20210402
    depends_on:
      - frontend
    container_name: selenium-hub
    ports:
      - "4442:4442"
      - "4443:4443"
      - "4444:4444"

  frontend:
    build:
      context: frontend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.nginx
    image: frontend:latest
    volumes:
      - ./frontend/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
    depends_on:
      - backend
    ports:
      - '8000:80'
```

```
class DragAndDropTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        caps = {'browserName': os.getenv('BROWSER', 'chrome')}
        #address = os.getenv('NODE_HUB_ADDRESS')
        self.browser = webdriver.Remote(
            command_executor=f'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
            desired_capabilities=caps
        )

    def test_drag_and_drop(self):
        browser = self.browser
        browser.get('http://localhost:8000/upload')

        dropzone = browser.find_element_by_css_selector(".file-dropzone")
        #dropzone.drop_files("Image Pasted at 2021-1-28 10-02.png")
        driver.implicitly_wait(10) # seconds

        print(element.text)
        self.assertIn('Drag or add your files here', element.text)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a docker container, `localhost` means the container, not your host machine. If you want to connect to your `frontend` container, you should write `frontend:80`

That will work only because you use `docker-compose`, which automatically creates a new docker network when you run a configuration with docker compose. If you were using only the cli, you would have to create a docker network and link each container to it.

Comment: yes I understood the issue about localhost. where do I put the `frontend:80`? should I put it under `services.chrome.ports`? then I get an error saying it only allow objects or number :-/

Comment: No, you should write `browser.get("http://frontend:80/upload")`, unless I misunderstood you are you are not running this function in a container

Comment: I am running that function in a container. I understand container's `localhost` is not same as host's localhost. What should the `docker-compose.yaml` file look like? where do I put the `frontend:80`. Or are you saying my yaml file is ok and I just need to adjust the function to be `browser.get("http://frontend:80/upload")`?

Comment: Yes ! Your yaml is okay, and you should adjust the function :)